# Facebook graph api - can't delete status (unexpected error)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to delete a status I have manually posted on Facebook.

My application is using the scope:

```
email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, read_stream, export_stream, publish_actions
```

When I try to delete the status (using PHP SDK, and Graph API), I get:

```
OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
```

My PHP Code is:

```
try {
    $facebook->api("/STATUS_ID","DELETE");
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using facebook in combination with wordpress, if that's relevant somehow

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: At most apps can delete stuff that was created using the same app. But for user status posts, I’m not sure if an app can delete them even in that scenario – the docs say nothing about deleting.

Comment: you can delete status posts if the facebook app create them (just checked from ios app)